# GIMP 2.10.6 hangs when querying plugins on initial startup

Tags: gimp

I am running Debian buster and recently upgraded gimp to version 2.10.6.  Upon starting gimp (I removed my gimp profile folder so it should be a fresh start), gimp hangs when starting to query plugins.  I initially had xsane installed, and gimp would hang indefinitely querying xsane.  After uninstalling xsane, gimp hangs querying what I presume is the next plugin installed.

In addition to this, whenever I have to kill gimp, it refuses to start at all until I perform a full system restart; it doesn't even open the splash screen, just hangs with no console output and no apparent activity of any kind.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging, it seems the problem only occurs if `libopenblas` is installed along with `gimp` (I had Julia installed, which depends on `libopenblas`).  See [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=903514).  Uninstalling `libopenblas` seems to fix the problem.